# Set of solutions of non linear system of equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a non-linear system of equations in Matlab and I would like to find the set of its solutions. The system is represented below.
[image]

Imagine for a moment that the Matlab function `mvncdf` can be used together with `solve`. My system of equations looks like this

```
clear
%SOME VALUES USED BELOW
U1true=1;
U2true=-1;
U3true=-2;
U4true=1;
rhotrue=-0.5;
mutrue=[0 0];
sigmatrue=[2*(1-rhotrue) 1-rhotrue; 1-rhotrue 2*(1-rhotrue)];

%SET VARIABLES
syms U1 U2 U3 U4 rho 

%SOLVE SYSTEM WITH 6 EQUATIONS
S=solve(mvncdf([ U1  -U2+U1], [0 0], [2*(1-rho) 1-rho; 1-rho 2*(1-rho)])==mvncdf([ U1true  -U2true+U1true], mutrue, sigmatrue) ,...
        mvncdf([ U2   U2-U1], [0 0], [2*(1-rho) 1-rho; 1-rho 2*(1-rho)])==mvncdf([ U2true   U2true-U1true], mutrue, sigmatrue),...
        mvncdf([-U1  -U2],    [0 0], [2*(1-rho) 1-rho; 1-rho 2*(1-rho)])==mvncdf([-U1true  -U2true],        mutrue, sigmatrue),...
        mvncdf([ U3  -U4+U3], [0 0], [2*(1-rho) 1-rho; 1-rho 2*(1-rho)])==mvncdf([ U3true  -U4true+U3true], mutrue, sigmatrue) ,...
        mvncdf([ U4   U4-U3], [0 0], [2*(1-rho) 1-rho; 1-rho 2*(1-rho)])==mvncdf([ U4true   U4true-U3true], mutrue, sigmatrue),...
        mvncdf([-U3  -U4],    [0 0], [2*(1-rho) 1-rho; 1-rho 2*(1-rho)])==mvncdf([-U3true  -U4true],        mutrue, sigmatrue));

%DISPLAY SOLUTIONS    
M=[S.U1,S.U2,S.U3,S.U4, S.rho];
```

This approach clearly does not work for many reasons, most importantly because `mvncdf` cannot be used together with `solve`, as discussed [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/357799-solve-equation-with-bivariate-normal-cdf-in-it) for example.

As an alternative method to solve my system, I thought about using `slicesample` as follows

[image]

This code implements my idea.

```
%MAIN
clear
rng default 

Utrue=[1;-1;-2;1];
rhotrue=-0.5;

number = 100000; 
initials=[Utrue;rhotrue]; %[U1;U2;U3;U4;rho]
rnd = slicesample(initials,number,'pdf',@dens);

%ANCILLARY FUNCTIONS TO SAVE
function density=dens(param)
         T=10^(-6); 

         if param(end)>=1 || param(end)<=-1 %rho outside (-1,1)
            density=0; %force density to be equal to zero
         else

            Utrue=[1;-1;-2;1];
            rhotrue=-0.5;

            mutrue=[0 0];
            sigmatrue=[2*(1-rhotrue) 1-rhotrue; 1-rhotrue 2*(1-rhotrue)];

            truth=mvncdf([ Utrue(1)  -Utrue(2)+Utrue(1);...
                        Utrue(2)   Utrue(2)-Utrue(1);...
                       -Utrue(1)  -Utrue(2)     ;...
                        Utrue(3)  -Utrue(4)+Utrue(3);...
                        Utrue(4)   Utrue(4)-Utrue(3);...
                       -Utrue(3)  -Utrue(4)], mutrue, sigmatrue);

           density=exp(-criterion(param,truth)/T); 
         end
end

function Q=criterion(param, truth)
         U=param(1:end-1);
         rho=param(end);
         mu=[0,0];
         sigma=[2*(1-rho) 1-rho; 1-rho 2*(1-rho)];
         candidates=mvncdf([ U(1)  -U(2)+U(1);...
                             U(2)   U(2)-U(1);...
                            -U(1)  -U(2)     ;...
                             U(3)  -U(4)+U(3);...
                             U(4)   U(4)-U(3);...
                            -U(3)  -U(4)], mu, sigma);

         Q=(candidates(1)-truth(1))^2+(candidates(2)-truth(2))^2+(candidates(3)-truth(3))^2+...
           (candidates(4)-truth(4))^2+(candidates(5)-truth(5))^2+(candidates(6)-truth(6))^2; %this is zero at a solution of the system

end
```

**Question**: using the approach that I propose, as I increase the variable `number` I get more and more solutions for different values of `rho`, which is in line with comment above that the system has one and only one solution with respect to U for every value of `rho`. However, to span the entire `(-1,1)` interval for `rho` it seems to me that I would need to set the variable `number` immensely high. Do you have (i) suggestions that can help me to improve the code above to solve this issue, or (ii) better approaches to provide the set of solutions of my system of equations?

Comment: Could you describe the problem in Math?

Comment: @Royi, I don't know how to post mathematical symbols here. Do you know how I can do that? The system of equations is described in the first quadrant (where I use the command `solve`)

Comment: It's really hard for me to understand the problem from the code. Regarding Math, you can embed images with Math from [Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

Comment: @Royi, OK I'll do that

Comment: @Royi Let me know if it looks better now. Thanks

Comment: I will have a look. By the way I answered your question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875160.